# Want to store response to cURL request, but the request itself is also getting stored. How to silence it?

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to run the following line in bash:

```
var=$(curl -Sid $'my_message\r\n' "http://localhost:9000" > my_file)
```

where `localhost:9000` is just a simple echo server.

However, when I look at my_file, this is what gets printed:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 159
Content-Type: text/plain

POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

my_message
```

How can I ensure only the following (the response) gets printed?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/plain

my_message
```

I tried to use the `-s` and `-S` flags but they don't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @user71611, can't you just pipe `curl`'s output to some kind of filter (`grep`, or `sed`/`awk`, or anything else) before redirecting to `my_file`?

Comment: I considered that approach (I can ignore 4th through 10th lines), but it's hard to get the Content-Length to work out (should be 12 not 159). Is there some flag I can set? Thanks

Comment: @user71611, if you tell me what is the rule by which you get only those 5 lines in ouput (4 + 1 empty line), I can possibly help. As in, _why do you get the second (or maybe the last?) `Conent-Length` but the first `Content-Type`?_ (Sorry if my scarse nowledge of the HTTP requests topic makes my question seems stupid.)

Comment: The message itself is of length 12 ("my_message\r\n"). So, when I ping the server normally (with Netcat on Terminal) I get the response you see in the second box. But when I use curl in my bash file, I get the top response. For some reason, it is counting the entire HTML request that curl generates as being part of the message and echoing it, so it says `Content-Length: 159`. I want it to only count the actual message content ("my_message\r\n") and echo only that. Once again, that is the normal behaviour when I run `nc localhost -C 9000`. Sorry if I was not clear. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: `var=$(curl ... | awk '/^\r$/{f++}f!=1' file)` should do it then.

Comment: But I didn't understand why don't you set up your server to echo just the content without headers

Comment: Hey @oguzismail, Thanks for the `awk` help! the problem with using grep or awk is that, for `Content-Length` it's hard to get the length of the actual message itself rather than the length of the whole HTTP request (including the headers). When I run with Netcat, it behaves that way and ignores the headers. I tried using Netcat in bash too (`output=$(printf 'my_message\r\n' | nc localhost -C 9000)`), but that would not end execution. Actually if you have any advice on using `nc` in bash, that would be great too. Thanks again!